# Almost two-point homogeneous spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces

I define a NICE space to be a connected Riemannian manifold $M$ such that for any two distinct points $p,q\in M$, there exists an isometry $R_{p,q}$ exchanging these two points (that is such that $R_{p,q}(p)=q$ and $R_{p,q}(q)=p$).

Every connected 2-point homogeneous space (defined by Hsien-Chung Wang) is clearly NICE.

Moreover, a cartesian product of NICE spaces is itself NICE.

Do you know if NICE manifolds have been studied and classified?

Comment: Symmetric spaces are important examples too (most of them are not 2-point homogeneous).

Comment: This is the definition of a weakly symmetric space: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-2432-7_15